# Remove ggplot2 geom_polygon Buffering

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to plot three polygons based on the example provided on the ggplot2 site [geom_polygon](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_polygon.html).  However it seems to force some buffering around the image despite setting xlim and ylim, is there a way to remove this buffering so the polygons go to the edge?

```
library(ggplot2)

ids <- factor(1:3)
values <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  value = 1:3)

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each=4),
  x = c( -3, 0, 0, -3,
         -3, 0, 3, -3,
          0, 3, 3, 0 ),
  y = c( -3,-3, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 3, 3,
         -3,-3, 3, 0 )
  )

datapoly <- merge( values, positions, by=c('id'))

mnp.latent.plot <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x=x,y=y, alpha=0.5)) +
geom_polygon(aes(fill=value, group=id)) + xlim(-3,3) + ylim(-3,3) +   
guides(fill=FALSE,alpha=FALSE)

plot(mnp.latent.plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the  xlim and ylim inside `coord_cartesian`:

```
mnp.latent.plot <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = 0.5)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value, group = id)) + 
  guides(fill = FALSE, alpha = FALSE) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3))

plot(mnp.latent.plot)
```

[image]